# how to print a string in 16*16 Dot Matrix from AVR

Tags: microcontroller, avr, led

I want to output the string "LED GAME" as indicated in picture . But in Dot matrix , there are only 16 + 16 = 32 pins . is there any way to print a string from avr to dotmatrix ?

[image]

Comment: You would need to do a raster scan - cycle through all the rows continuously, turning on the relevant column bits for each row. So long as you do this fast enough the eye sees it as a continuous display, just like and old-fashioned CRT.

Comment: Consider using 4 8x8 LED matrix displays, and driving them with something like the [MAX7219](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/display-power-control/MAX7219.html). There's plenty of code out there for driving these things with AVRs and how to hook them up. Simple 'row at a time' multiplexing will probably not look bright enough with a 1/16 duty cycle.

Comment: You can also buy 16x16 LED matrix displays with control hardware built in, but I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How can you identify Pin 1 Of Dot matrix ?

The leftmost pin of dot matrix on the opposite site of the label "2088BH-B" is pin 1 .

You can get a complete idea from the two following picture . 
[image]

[image]

Hope this will help you a lot . you can also try the following code which is written for showing 9 in dot matrix ( compiler: micro-C)

```
void main() 
{
     DDRB = 0b11111111;
     DDRC = 0b11111111;
     while(1)
     {
           PORTB=0b00000000;  // 1
           PORTC=0b10000000;
            Delay_us(5);

           PORTB=0b00000000;       //2
           PORTC=0b01000000;
            Delay_us(5);

           PORTB=0b00000000;          //3
           PORTC=0b00100000;
            Delay_us(5);

           PORTB=0b00000000;             //4
           PORTC=0b00010000;
            Delay_us(5);

           PORTB=0b10011110;  // 5
           PORTC=0b00001000;
            Delay_us(5);

           PORTB=0b10010010;       //6
           PORTC=0b00000100;
            Delay_us(5);

           PORTB=0b10010010;          //7
           PORTC=0b00000010;
           Delay_us(5);

           PORTB=0b11111110;             //8
           PORTC=0b00000001;
           Delay_us(5);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Most LED matrixes are internally built up like this example here:

[image: LED matrix]

For a 16x16 LED matrix you thus have 16 pins for the rows and 16 pins for the columns. To see how your specific matrix is built up, you'll have to find its datasheet.

To write anything on the display, you will set the first row to ON, all others to OFF and activate the cols you need. After a delay, you will set the first row to OFF, the second row to ON and activate the cols you want to see in the second row. You will iterate through all rows like this. As the delay will be pretty short, your eyes aren't fast enough to see that the LEDs are off most of the time.

I would suggest to use a timer interrupt on you microcontroller and iterate through the rows in the interrupt routine. That way you can easily use the microcontroller for other things without worrying too much about timing issues.